# android stopservice after 25minutes

Tags: android

I have an android application that gets user location every 2 minutes using `requestLocationUpdates` service, so now once it reaches 25 minutes I want the running service to be stopped. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a timer (1500000 = 25 minutes in milliseconds):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { 
            public void run() { 
                //stop your service here
            } 
}, 0, 1500000);
```

Comment: timer.schedule shoud be enought